# Dependency injection at runtime using Ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

How do I inject a specific dependency using Ninject when which class to inject is only determined at runtime? I have an interface and implmentations as follows:

```
public interface ICompanyDAL
{
   Company LoadProfile(int companyID);
}

public class TechCompanySqlDAL : ICompanyDAL
{
    Company LoadProfile(int companyID)
    {
        //Call Stored procs related to TechCompany
        //Populate Model class TechCompany which is derived from abstract class Company
    }
}

public class BankingCompanySqlDAL : ICompanyDAL
{
    Company LoadProfile(int companyID)
    {
        //Call Stored procs related to BankingCompany
        //Populate Model class BankingCompany which is derived from abstract class Company
    }
}
```

I have a service class that needs to call one of the two concrete classes as follows.

```
public class CompanyService
{
    private readonly ICompanyDAL companyDAL;

    public CompanyHousingService(ICompanyDAL compDAL)
    {
        this.companyDAL = compDAL;
    }

    public Company LoadProfile(int companyID, CompanyType type)
    {
        if(type == CompanyType.Tech)
           //Need to call TechCompanyDAL
        else if (type == CompanyType.Banking)
           //Need to call BankingCompanyDAL
    }   

}
```

I don't want Service class to be dependent on any of the concrete classes, because those might change. Also we might add more company typese. So how do I inject ICompanyDAL into the service based on reflection.

I am also open to suggestions on changing the above pattern if anyone explains a better alternative.

Comment: You need to inject two `ICompanyDAL` dependencies.

Comment: You might also want to consider a generic `ICompanyDAL` interface

Comment: Inject a single factory class that returns a ICompanyDAL.

Comment: I like both the ideas -- using generic interface and using a factory class. Would you guys mind providing a bit of code to get me started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `ICompanyDAL` generic and inject two dependencies into `CompanyService` like this:

```
public interface ICompanyDAL<T> where T:Company
{
    T LoadProfile(int companyID);
}

public class TechCompanySqlDAL : ICompanyDAL<TechCompany>
{
    public TechCompany LoadProfile(int companyID)
    {
        //Call Stored procs related to TechCompany
        //Populate Model class TechCompany which is derived from abstract class Company
    }
}

public class BankingCompanySqlDAL : ICompanyDAL<BankingCompany>
{
    public BankingCompany LoadProfile(int companyID)
    {
        //Call Stored procs related to BankingCompany
        //Populate Model class BankingCompany which is derived from abstract class Company
    }
}

public class CompanyService
{
    private readonly ICompanyDAL<BankingCompany> bankingCompanyDAL;
    private readonly ICompanyDAL<TechCompany> techCompanyDAL;

    public CompanyService(ICompanyDAL<BankingCompany> banking_company_dal, ICompanyDAL<TechCompany> tech_company_dal)
    {
        bankingCompanyDAL = banking_company_dal;
        techCompanyDAL = tech_company_dal;
    }

    public Company LoadProfile(int companyID, CompanyType type)
    {
        if (type == CompanyType.Tech)
            return techCompanyDAL.LoadProfile(companyID);
        else if (type == CompanyType.Banking)
            return bankingCompanyDAL.LoadProfile(companyID);

        //handle case of invalid type 
    }   
}
```

And here is how you would register the dependencies and resolve your `CompanyService` object:

```
StandardKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

kernel.Bind<ICompanyDAL<TechCompany>>().To<TechCompanySqlDAL>();
kernel.Bind<ICompanyDAL<BankingCompany>>().To<BankingCompanySqlDAL>();

var service = kernel.Get<CompanyService>();
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There are many approaches to solve that you can use ganerics for example, but one of them is this:

> you can change the *ctor* dependency to `IEnumerable<ICompanyDAL>`. 
>   so maybe this will works fine to you, see the code below:

```
public interface ICompanyDAL
{
   CompanyType CompanyType {get;}
   Company LoadProfile(int companyID);
}

public class TechCompanySqlDAL : ICompanyDAL
{
    public CompanyType CompanyType => CompanyType.Tech;
    Company LoadProfile(int companyID)
    {
        //Call Stored procs related to TechCompany
        //Populate Model class TechCompany which is derived from abstract class Company
    }
}

public class BankingCompanySqlDAL : ICompanyDAL
{
    public CompanyType CompanyType => CompanyType.Banking;
    Company LoadProfile(int companyID)
    {
        //Call Stored procs related to BankingCompany
        //Populate Model class BankingCompany which is derived from abstract class Company
    }
}
```

Now the ***Service***:

```
public class CompanyService
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ICompanyDAL>compDALs;

    public CompanyHousingService(IEnumerable<ICompanyDAL> compDALs)
    {
        this.companyDALs = compDALs;
    }

    public Company LoadProfile(int companyID, CompanyType type)      
       => companyDALs.FirstOrDefault(s => s.CompanyType==type)?.LoadProfile(companyID); 
}
```

Comment: Note: the `IEnumerable` injected into the ctor by Ninject's Multi-Injection feature should be materialized (enumerated) in the constructor, otherwise it can lead to nasty concurrency issue. So instead of injecting an `IEnumerable` one might consider to inject an `IList` or an array `[]` instead.

Comment: Sure, my bad XD, i coded this with the ````IEnumerable```` , just by the didatic.

Comment: Well that's ok, the issue is not well known and i regard it as a bug. I suggested to remove support for `IEnumerable` injection but i believe it was kept to be backwards compatible. I'd advise against using it though, because it is a trap.